# Find all strings that have more than 255 characters that are not whitespace in PHP

Tags: php, regex, string, grep

The following command will find me those strings which have more than 255 characters that are not white space.

```
egrep -norq '[^ ]{255,}'
```

If I have a string in `$content`, how would I find (in PHP) all the occurrences of strings that are longer than 255 characters, and save those occurrences so that later I can echo them?

Comment: Someone already answered your question, but one small thing I noticed is how you said "more than 255", but you used the quantifier `{255,}`, which would grab strings 255 characters long or more (i.e. it includes 255 itself, instead of being more than 255, which would be `{256,}`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PHP you use `preg_match` for matching:

```
// assuming $content is your input
if ( preg_match_all('/\S{255,}/', $content , $m ) ) {
    // save $content
}
```

- `\S` => matches any non space character
- `{255,}` => makes sure there are at least 255 characters in input

Comment: Awesome. And if it finds more than one occurrence it will be in $m? as m[0], m[1]..?

Comment: actually to need more than we need `preg_match_all` and all those matches will be in `$m[0]`